# Show/hide additional information when radio button clicked

Tags: jquery, html

I have a table with radio buttons in each row. This table also
contains additional information for each row. I would like to
show the detailed information only for the selected radio button row
not for all the rows. The style of the selected rb should also change when
selected.

Radio

```
<td class='v1'><input type='radio' name='price' value='rbt' id='rbt'>". oci_result($stmt, 'INFO_1') . "</td>\n"
```

Sub information:

```
"<tr><td class='e4' colspan='2'>Subcell1</td><td class='e4' colspan='2'>INFO_1</td><td class='e4'>EUR 194</td><td class='e4'>EUR 194</td><td class='e4'>EUR 194</td><td class='e4'>free</td><td class='e4'>EUR 310</td><td class='e4'>free</td><td class='e4'>free</td></tr>\n"

"<tr><td class='e4' colspan='2'>Subcell1</td><td class='e4' colspan='2'>INFO_2</td><td class='e4'>not included</td><td class='e4'>not included</td><td class='e4'>EUR 230</td><td class='e4'>free</td><td class='e4'>not included</td><td class='e4'>free</td><td class='e4'>free</td></tr>\n"
    . "</tr>\n"
    . "</tr>\n"


$(".e4").hide();
            $('input[type=radio]').click(function(){
             $(this).closest("tr").find(".e4").show();
         });
```

The sub information applies to several rows, but the goal is to show only the selected row.

Maybe JQuery can solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Its strongly recomended to show your code when you are posting a question.Otherwise it will be too difficult to help you

Comment: Code posted. Still not working.

Answer (score 1):

may be you can use the `.parent(), .closest() and .find()` function of jquery to achieve this, please look in to the documentation, you will get an idea about how you can do this

Answer (score 0):

You can use closest() to get the nearest element

[.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

Answer (score 0):

you give no code, so I will not either.

try `.hide` `.show` or `.toggle`  I think toggle may be best.